# How to get price from App Store

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore

If we look at this website [appshopper.com](http://appshopper.com), that website seems to automatically update its prices with the current prices of the App Store.

How can I do that?

Comment: This seems to be a question about designing a website, not a question about using an Apple product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you need is available through [Apple's RSS Generator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss).